# Change Key Value separator of HashMap for toString

Tags: java

When we print a HashMap in java using toString(), it is something like

```
{ "a"="b" }
```

How can i print it like

```
{"a":"b"}
```

Comment: `String.replaceAll()` with a proper regex?

Comment: Good luck writing that regex to handle all cases (e.g. `=` in keys/values).

Comment: Would there be anything wrong with just writing a helper method to handle printing your `Map` in a JSONesque way?  Also, I would be surprised if there weren't already some open source library which can do this.

Comment: toString works just fine. Why do you need a `:` instead of a `=`? I think you have a xy-problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't configure the sign, so you basically need to reimplement the `HashMap.toString()` method.

Check out the source code for `toString()` in [`AbstractMap`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/AbstractMap.java#510):

```
public String toString() {
    Iterator<Entry<K,V>> i = entrySet().iterator();
    if (! i.hasNext())
        return "{}";

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append('{');
    for (;;) {
        Entry<K,V> e = i.next();
        K key = e.getKey();
        V value = e.getValue();
        sb.append(key   == this ? "(this Map)" : key);
        sb.append('=');
        sb.append(value == this ? "(this Map)" : value);
        if (! i.hasNext())
            return sb.append('}').toString();
        sb.append(", ");
    }
}
```

Hopefully, it should be pretty easy to see how to change that from `=` to `:`. You'd also need to make this a method which takes a `Map<?, ?>`, and uses the reference to that map instead of `this`:

```
public static String toStringWithColon(Map<?, ?> map) {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

More simple, but not recursive

```
Map<String,String> mss; // For example, or Map<K,V>
String output="{";
boolean first=true;
for (String K: mss.keySet())
    {
    if (!first) output+=", ";
    output+=K+":"+mss.get(K);
    first=false;
    }
output+="}";
```

Comment: Yes, simpler, but it doesn't handle the potentially-infinite recursion if `K` or `mss.get(K)` is `mss`. I concede that is an unusual edge case, but it's one of those "nah, it'll never happen"-becomes-"PITA production bug" cases. Also, one should use `entrySet` if both key and corresponding value are required, and use a StringBuilder to accumulate strings in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Extend HashMap and override toString() method. You cam see current realisation of this method in JDK, so just change what You want.

Comment: Extending `HashMap` is an awkward approach, because it requires you to construct all of your maps as this subclass, and it presupposes that you will only ever want to print maps with colons (what if, aside from this specific circumstance, you want `=`). If all that is required is to print the map, a method taking a (`Hash`)`Map` as a parameter is a more flexible approach.

Answer (score 0):

The separator is not configurable. HashMap inherits from [AbstractMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/Java/util/AbstractMap.html#toString--), and AbstractMap's `toString` method is documented as follows:

> Each key-value mapping is rendered as the key followed by an equals sign ("=") followed by the associated value.

Note that it doesn't say "the key followed by the current delimiter ...", so this aspect is not configurable.

You will thus have to create your own method to convert the map as you need to a string (hint: Use StringBuilder for this).

---

If your goal is to generate JSON, which appears to be the case here, given the choice of separator, there are more issues involved than just changing the separator. For example, you also have to escape quotation marks and other special characters (using the backslash character) that appear in each string.